# How to configure Serilog for WCF

Tags: serilog

I am upgrading our old application for Serilog... One of the existing functionality is ... When log level = ERROR, it will log into local file and send 'WCF' request to the remote server, remote server will update database... 
Basically it will log into multiple source(local file, remote database by sending wcf request) if it level is 'ERROR'. 
I understand using 'rollingfile' appender to logging into local file. 
However, i do not know how to configure 'WCF Service' for Serilog... is there any 'WCF SINK' can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing there's no generic sink that makes "WCF" calls... You'd have to [build your own sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink), implementing the calls you need.

You can see a list of documented sinks in the "[Provided Sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks)" page on Serilog's wiki, and you can also see available [sinks in NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22Serilog%22%2C%22Sink%22).